# ruby extension for clang crash with segfault when GC delete Index object

Tags: ruby, clang, llvm-clang, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to write a little ruby extension for the c interface of clang. I am focusing on the CXIndex structure that I wrapp in a Clangc::Index class.

I am able to compile it, load the module and create  some Clangc::Index class like in this test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "minitest/autorun"
require "clangc"

class TestIndexCreation < MiniTest::Test
  def test_new_index_dont_exclude_decl_from_pch_and_dont_display_diagnostics
    assert_equal Clangc::Index, Clangc::Index.new(false, false).class
  end
  def test_new_index_exclude_decl_from_pch_and_dont_display_diagnostics
    assert_equal Clangc::Index, Clangc::Index.new(true, false).class
  end
  def test_new_index_dont_exclude_decl_from_pch_and_display_diagnostics
    assert_equal Clangc::Index, Clangc::Index.new(false, true).class
  end
  def test_new_index_exclude_decl_from_pch_and_display_diagnostics
    assert_equal Clangc::Index, Clangc::Index.new(true, true).class
  end
end
```

The problem comes when I try to do this kind of stuff with my module:
the C way (which works well)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clang-c/Index.h"
/*
compile with:
clang -lclang -o index_manipulation index_manipulation.c
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(1, 1);
  clang_CXIndex_setGlobalOptions(Index, CXGlobalOpt_None);
  printf("%u\n", CXGlobalOpt_None);
  clang_disposeIndex(Index);

  Index = clang_createIndex(1, 1);
  clang_CXIndex_setGlobalOptions(Index, CXGlobalOpt_ThreadBackgroundPriorityForEditing);
  printf("%u\n", CXGlobalOpt_ThreadBackgroundPriorityForEditing);
  clang_disposeIndex(Index);

//       CXGlobalOpt_ForIndexing); //CXGlobalOptFlags

  return 0;
}
```

And the ruby way which crash when the GC try to clean the Index instance created with the option Threadbackgroundpriorityforediting :

```
# index global options test
#Clangc::GlobalOptFlags.constants
#=> [:None, :Threadbackgroundpriorityforindexing, :Threadbackgroundpriorityforediting, :Threadbackgroundpriorityforall]

class TestIndexGlobalOptions < MiniTest::Test
  def setup
    @cindex = Clangc::Index.new(true, true)
  end
  def test_index_set_global_options_None
    flags = Clangc::GlobalOptFlags::None
    @cindex.global_options = flags
    assert_equal flags, @cindex.global_options
  end
  def test_index_set_global_options_editing
    flags =  Clangc::GlobalOptFlags::Threadbackgroundpriorityforediting
    @cindex.global_options = flags
    assert_equal flags, @cindex.global_options
  end
end
```

Here is the output of the tests (note that I have included some debugging outputs in the C code):

```
ruby test/Index_tests.rb
Run options: --seed 10378
# Running:

New class allocated at 0x139bfe0
New class ptr 0x139bfe0 with Index ptr 0x1057b30
.New class allocated at 0x1350a30
New class ptr 0x1350a30 with Index ptr 0x13769f0
.

Finished in 0.000871s, 2297.2451 runs/s, 2297.2451 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
SENTINEL index ptr 0x1057b30
SENTINEL class ptr 0x139bfe0
SENTINEL free end
SENTINEL index ptr 0x2013769f0
test/Index_tests.rb: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0003e800002782
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000f60 TOP    [FINISH]


-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f175c9cfb9d RBP: 0x0000000000de99f0 RSP: 0x00007ffc5a05a000
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x00000002013769f0 RCX: 0x000000007fffffe1
 RDX: 0x00007f175fb29970 RDI: 0x00000002013769f0 RSI: 0x000000000000001f
  R8: 0x00000002013769f0  R9: 0x0000000000000000 R10: 0x00007f176018e700
 R11: 0x0000000000000000 R12: 0x0000000001040000 R13: 0x0000000001042648
 R14: 0x000000000103e060 R15: 0x00007ffc5a05a048 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2 [0x7f175fcc2915]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2 [0x7f175fcc2b4c]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2 [0x7f175fb9cd4b]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2 [0x7f175fc5432e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6 [0x7f175f7bd540]
/usr/lib/libclang.so(clang_disposeIndex+0x1d) [0x7f175c9cfb9d]
/home/cedlemo/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/clangc-0.0.1/clangc/clangc.so(c_Index_struct_free+0x2c) [0x7f175d79ff7c]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2 [0x7f175fbb3d21]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2(rb_gc_call_finalizer_at_exit+0x289) [0x7f175fbbd169]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2(ruby_cleanup+0x3e8) [0x7f175fba3668]
/usr/lib/libruby.so.2.2(ruby_run_node+0x25) [0x7f175fba38b5]
ruby [0x4008ab]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f175f7aa800]
ruby(_start+0x29) [0x4008d9]
```

I understand that it is related to clang_disposeIndex but I can't find out how to solve this.

here is the files of my extension:

```
├── ext
│   └── clangc
│       ├── clangc.c
│       ├── class_Index.c
│       ├── class_Index.h
│       ├── constants.c
│       ├── constants.h
│       ├── extconf.rb
```

class_Index.h

```
#ifndef INDEX_H
#define INDEX_H
  #include <ruby/ruby.h>
typedef struct Index_t {
    CXIndex data; 
} Index_t;

  VALUE generate_Index_under(VALUE, VALUE);
#endif //INDEX_H
```

class_Index.c

```
/*Index ruby class*/
#include "clang-c/Index.h"
#include "class_Index.h"
#include "stdio.h"

static void
c_Index_struct_free(Index_t *s)
{
  if(s)
  {

    if(s->data)
    {
      printf("SENTINEL index ptr %p\n", s->data);
      clang_disposeIndex(s->data); 
    }
    printf("SENTINEL class ptr %p\n", s);
    ruby_xfree(s);
    printf("SENTINEL free end\n");
   }
}  
static VALUE
c_Index_struct_alloc( VALUE klass)
{
  Index_t *i;
  i = (Index_t *) ruby_xmalloc(sizeof(Index_t));
  printf("New class allocated at %p\n", i);
  i->data = NULL;
  return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, NULL, c_Index_struct_free,(void *) i );
}

static VALUE
c_Index_initialize(VALUE self, VALUE excl_decls_from_PCH, VALUE display_diagnostics) {
  Index_t *i;
  Data_Get_Struct(self, Index_t, i);
  uint e= (excl_decls_from_PCH == Qtrue) ? 1 : 0;
  uint d= (display_diagnostics == Qtrue) ? 1 : 0;

  i->data = clang_createIndex( e, d);
  printf("New class %p with Indew %p\n", i, i->data);
  return self;
}
static VALUE
c_Index_set_global_options(VALUE self, VALUE options) {
  Index_t *i;
  Data_Get_Struct(self, Index_t, i);
  if (TYPE(options) == T_FIXNUM || TYPE(options) == T_BIGNUM)
    clang_CXIndex_setGlobalOptions(i,NUM2UINT(options));
  else
    rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "invalid type for input");
  return Qnil;
}
static VALUE
c_Index_get_global_options(VALUE self) {
  Index_t *i;
  Data_Get_Struct(self, Index_t, i);

  return UINT2NUM(clang_CXIndex_getGlobalOptions(i));
}
VALUE
generate_Index_under(VALUE module, VALUE superclass){
  VALUE klass = rb_define_class_under(module, "Index", superclass);
  rb_define_alloc_func(klass, c_Index_struct_alloc);
  rb_define_private_method(klass, "initialize", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(c_Index_initialize), 2);
  rb_define_method(klass, "global_options=", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(c_Index_set_global_options), 1);
  rb_define_method(klass, "global_options", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(c_Index_get_global_options), 0);
  return klass;
}
```

clangc.c

```
#include <ruby/ruby.h>
#include "clang-c/Index.h"

#include "constants.h"
#include "class_Index.h"
void Init_clangc(void) {
  VALUE m_clangc = rb_define_module("Clangc");
  init_clang_enums_to_constants(m_clangc);
  generate_Index_under(m_clangc, rb_cObject);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the errors, the corrected code is :

```
static VALUE
c_Index_set_global_options(VALUE self, VALUE options) {
  Index_t *i;
  Data_Get_Struct(self, Index_t, i);
  if (TYPE(options) == T_FIXNUM || TYPE(options) == T_BIGNUM)
    //clang_CXIndex_setGlobalOptions(i,NUM2UINT(options));
    clang_CXIndex_setGlobalOptions(i->data,NUM2UINT(options));
  else
    rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "invalid type for input");
  return Qnil;
}
static VALUE
c_Index_get_global_options(VALUE self) {
  Index_t *i;
  Data_Get_Struct(self, Index_t, i);

//  return UINT2NUM(clang_CXIndex_getGlobalOptions(i));
  return UINT2NUM(clang_CXIndex_getGlobalOptions(i->data));
}
```